# How to update a field in a struct?

Tags: c, eclipse, struct

I have a `struct` that has days in it. I wrote some long code with Eclipse and I put the struct in a C file in a different file from `main()`. Now, in `main()`, I wrote a function that goes to the `struct` and updates the `day` field - for some reason the field is not updated. I tried to debug this but the debugger suddenly stops if I put break points (Eclipse problem) - even though the code works but the result I get is wrong. So I added `printf` to see if the fields actually updates or not, and I found out they are not.

Here is the `struct`:

```
    typedef struct roomorder_t* Roomorder;

    struct roomorder_t {
        int room_id;
        int days_till_order;
        int order_hour;
    };

    // function in the same c file that updates the day
    void updateRoomOrderDay(Roomorder roomorder){
        int curr_day=roomorder->days_till_order;
        curr_day-=1;
        return;
    }

int GetRoomOrderDaysTillOrder(Roomorder roomorder){
    if(roomorder==NULL){
        return FAIL;
    }
    return roomorder->days_till_order;
}

    // here how i used the function in the main file to update :



     static void EscapeUpdateDay(Escape escape){
                     // here i wrote a code to find the roomorder struct i am 
                      //looking 
                     //for to update and i found it (curr_order)
                       Roomorder curr_order=setGetFirst(roomorders);
                       printf("days_till_order_before=d\n",GetRoomOrderDaysTillOrder(curr_order));
                        updateRoomOrderDay(curr_order);
printf("days_till_order_after=%d\n",GetRoomOrderDaysTillOrder(curr_order));

        }
```

> UPDATE: ok so the day did update but the opposite happend ! i added a
>   printf and an example to explain what happened : i printed the day
>   before the update and after , it did change but instead of
>   substracting one day it added a day for example :

```
//days_till_order_before=7 (before the update)
//days_till_order_after=8 (after the update)
```

> // also i did change the updateRoomOrderDay function to what you told
>   me.

```
roomorder->days_till_order-=1;
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to read the chapter on pointers

Comment: no i don't want to change every thing now and use pointers !!

Comment: the code is very very long and everything works perfectly but this ! i just want to know this is wrong right ??

Comment: Please do not alter the post so that answers do not make any sense anymore. Add to the end of the post

Comment: i thought i was doing the write thing lol ok i am really sorry !

Comment: Add code for `GetRoomOrderDaysTillOrder`

Comment: i have the code but i will ada it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just updating a local variable in the code

```
void updateRoomOrderDay(Roomorder roomorder){
    int curr_day=roomorder->days_till_order;
    curr_day-=1;
    return;
}
```

change it to ( i guess)

```
void updateRoomOrderDay(Roomorder roomorder){
    roomorder->days_till_order = roomorder->days_till_order - 1;
}
```

PS: `typedef struct roomorder_t* Roomorder;` - This is bad practice as you are hiding a pointer

*EDIT*

Now armed with the code

```
int GetRoomOrderDaysTillOrder(Roomorder roomorder){
    if(roomorder==NULL){
        return FAIL;
    }
    return roomorder->days_till_order;
}
```

Your semantics is incorrect. You are either returning a value or an error code. What is the value of FAIL?

Comment: thats not the problem :/ i mean it is wrong i will fix it but still the curr_order day fieled didn't change

Comment: Where is the `curr_xxxx` (you have two names here) in the structure?

Comment: i didn't understannd you question !!

Comment: curr_order is the struct i was looking for and i found it now i used the function updateRoomOrderDay to update it's day //

Comment: is this line correct ?? 
                               updateRoomOrderDay(curr_order);

Comment: am i here changing the actuall struct or a copy from it ??

Comment: I have not got a clue what you are trying to do. One minute it is `curr_order` next it is `curr_Day`. Neither are in the structure that is in the post

Comment: But you do not either in the structure!

Comment: _Now the curr_order day didn't update its day._ > What does this mean? What part of the structure should change?

Comment: i updated the question again !! this time the day changed but not correctly

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

In this portion of your code:

```
void updateRoomOrderDay(Roomorder roomorder){
    int curr_day=roomorder->days_till_order;
    curr_day-=1;
    return;
}
```

You are first storing the value of `roomorder->days_till_order` in an integer variable, then decrementing that integer variable's value by 1(which will have no effect on the value of `roomorder->days_till_order`), So, you need to change this portion to:

```
void updateRoomOrderDay(Roomorder roomorder){
    int curr_day=roomorder->days_till_order;
    curr_day-=1;
    roomorder->days_till_order = curr_day;
    return;
}
```

Or, you can do this:

```
void updateRoomOrderDay(Roomorder roomorder){
    roomorder->days_till_order -= 1;
    return;
}
```

Comment: i changed your answer instead of the question i am really sorry it was by mistake :\